# Docker container exits immediately after running or restarting PostgreSQL image

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am begginer with docker, and I stuck in place due to container restarting problem.
The problem occures when I try to restart an existing exited container, or create new container (after deleting old one) running:

```
docker run -d --name mempostgres \
    -v "/home/lukasz/lc_pg_data:/var/lib/pgsql/data:Z" \
    -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password \
    -e POSTGRES_DB=dbName \
    -p 5432:5432 \
    fedora/postgresql
```

My container always exits immediately with status "Exited(1)"

Inside the logs of my container i have:
[image]

However I don't have any PostgreSQL server running at this moment.

Comment: Not an answer but the image isn't really up to date. I would recommend to use the official postgres image: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Comment: If you are sure that there is no another Postgres running, delete that .pid file.

Comment: For me deleting the files helped. Well I didn't have any database or anything. it happened to me by initializing the pg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to kill that `postmaster` process.

`cat .../postmaster.pid`

The first number of this file is the PID of `postmaster` process.

Then, kill that process using:

`kill PID`

Finally, run a container, your problem should be fixed.

Comment: what is it? what does it do? and how does it lead to an error?

Answer (score 2):

`Postgres` should conatain password environmental variable as below:
`-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres`

Add also, `pgadmin` should have two environmental variables(`email` and `passworld`) as below:
`-e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=address@email.something' -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=postgresmaster'`

This is the email address used when setting up the initial administrator account to login to pgAdmin. This variable is required and must be set at launch time.

If these details are not given `postgres` and `pgadmin` will go to `exited` state.