# Docker Container exit immediately after running

Tags: sql-server, macos, docker

I'm a Docker newbie and tried to resolve the issue after checking similar SO questions without success. So please don't mark it as a duplicate .

Issue :

The container always exits immediately after its created and running.

I have tried to run the mssql instance using command

```
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Technocrat123’ -p 1433:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

when trying as similar SO link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599632/docker-container-is-not-running)

```
$ docker run -t -d --name microsoft/mssql-server-linux 0adcdf822722
```

got the following error ,

```
Unable to find image '0adcdf822722:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: repository 0adcdf822722 not found: does not exist or no pull access.
```

when tried to kill the process referring [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497437/docker-container-exits-immediately-after-running-or-restarting-postgresql-image)

```
Kill: illegal process id: PID
```

I'm using a mac machine. Thanks in advance.

Edit : 
After running the log after run command like

```
 docker logs 0adcdf822722
```

it shows

```
This is an evaluation version.  There are [160] days left in the evaluation period.
The SQL Server End-User License Agreement (EULA) must be accepted before SQL
Server can start. The license terms for this product can be downloaded from
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746388.

You can accept the EULA by specifying the --accept-eula command line option,
setting the ACCEPT_EULA environment variable, or using the mssql-conf tool.
```

But already in the run command I have set 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y'.

Comment: when your container exists (after doing the first command `docker run -e 'ACC...`. Perform `docker ps -a` to see the stopped container and check the logs with `docker logs container-id`. What are they showing?

Comment: I've executed the same command, so the image is pulled from https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/ and it's running fine for me. Do you have sufficient memory?

Comment: @lvthillo , I have added the logs . I have set 4 gb memory .

Comment: Hmm, when I check your run command it contains a bad quote but that's maybe because of the copy/paste. Maybe try to delete this container with `docker rm -fv container-id` and try it again by retyping the command or copying it from docker hub?

Comment: @lvthillo I will try it

Comment: @lvthillo thanks alot for pointing out the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the command you are running:

```
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Technocrat123’ -p 1433:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

**'Technocrat123’** should be **'Technocrat123'**. The typo is in the end: ’ vs '.

The correct command is:

```
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Technocrat123' -p 1433:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

Comment: whats the difference ?

Comment: thanks for your response , Can you please rewrite the command ? I 'm not able find the typo

Answer (score 11):

Your password (such as `Technocrat123`) doesn't meet the [complexity requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy?view=sql-server-2017). So try adding a non-alphanumeric characters such as exclamation point (`!`). Secondly, use double quotes instead of single.

To check for errors, run: `docker logs ID` (where `ID` is container ID from `docker ps`).

Comment: Thanks! For me, this was the issue. I followed this guide:
https://database.guide/how-to-install-sql-server-on-an-m1-mac-arm64/
And the person used  "bigStrongPwd" as password, which was intentionally too weak.

Comment: Thank you! complexity requirements were the issue for me here too. I planned on changing the password inside the image, so that was a little weird - also strange it gave no indication in the log. Thank you!

Comment: this worked for me after 2 hours of troubleshooting running linux mint as host, my password was just weak and process was exiting with code 1 immediately. THANKS A LOT

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=Sprpwd1234" --name sql_server_dev -p 1433:1433 -d store/microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-GA
```

Using (") instead of ('). Running Docker on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I was running Docker on Mac and trying to install sql-server. Initially, I was pasting the command provided here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker changing password. Then I would try to run the docker image. This gave me the said error "This is an evaluation version.....". I did an **additional** step, after running the command on the above link. I ran it again as docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Very_StrongPassword' -p 1401:1433 microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest. This kicked off installation of sql-server. This installation takes around 20-30 mins. Then the docker image is ready to use.